# CSS Button positioning

Tags: html, css

Basically when I want to move "About me" button Contact button moves but About me button doesn't move at all. 
Here's html

```
 <div id="damn">
    <img src="illtrythis.jpg" alter=" ">
   </div>

</head>


 <form>
 <input type="submit" class="aboutme" value="About me" >

 <input type="submit" class ="contact"  value="Contact">


 </form>
  </html>
```

Sorry for bad code,
I'm having problem with putting CSS into "code here so heres a screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AlTlY.jpg - first pic

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AlTlY.jpg - second pic

Comment: Put the css and I'll format it for you

Comment: Why did you put `<div>` inside `<head>` tag?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could put the code into the answer. If you're still having problems with that, make a jsFiddle (http://jsFiddle.com). It's VERY difficult for us to debug code properly when we can't edit and try things out.